# not to list products that are not in stock

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

i have a module that shows categories of virtuemart products in front page. 
I dont want the products that are not in stock available to be shown.

there is a function in the module code to select the products:

```
public static function _CountProduct($catids, $params)
{
    if ($catids == '*') {
        $_catids = $params->get('catid');
        $catids = self::_getChildCategories($_catids, $params);
        $catids = self::_getPublishCategories($catids);
    }
    if (empty($catids)) return;

    $limitation = 999;
    $source_group = null;
    $ordering_direction = $params->get('product_ordering_direction');
    $source_order = $params->get('source_order', 'group.featured');
    $p_special = $params->get('show_front');
    $categoryModel = VmModel::getModel('Category');
    $categoryModel->_noLimit = true;

    $list = array();
    if (!empty($catids)) {
        $productModel = VmModel::getModel('Product');
        $productModel = new VirtuemartModelProductExtend();
        $productModel->filter_order = $source_order;
        $productModel->specail_product = $p_special;
        $productModel->ordering_direction = $ordering_direction;
        $desc_maxlength = $params->get('item_des_maxlength');
        $items = $productModel->getProductListing($source_group, $limitation, true, true, false, true, $catids);
        $productModel->addImages($items);
        $ratingModel = VmModel::getModel('ratings');
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $item->title = $item->product_name;
            $item->id = $item->virtuemart_product_id;
            $item->description = $item->product_desc;
            self::getVmImages($item, $params);
            $item->short_desc = self::_cleanText($item->product_s_desc);
            $item->_description = self::_cleanText($item->description);
            $item->_description = ($item->_description != '') ? self::truncate($item->_description, $desc_maxlength) : self::truncate($item->short_desc, $desc_maxlength);
            $item->vote = $ratingModel->getVoteByProduct($item->virtuemart_product_id);
            $item->rating = $ratingModel->getRatingByProduct($item->virtuemart_product_id);
            $list[] = $item;
        }
    }


    return count($list);
}
```

how should i change this function to do so?
I'm using the last version of joomla and virtuemart.

any help would be appreciated. 
thanks

Comment: What cart component are you using? Virtuemart? Hikashop? What is the module - is a part of the cart component or a stand alone module?

Comment: I'm using virtuemart

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard Vm function - if you select **Configuration > Shopfront** on the right hand side there are options available for when products are out of stock...Change this to '**Do not display product**'.

[image: Hide products when out of stock]

Apologies for the delayed response, I have been away.

Regards
Donna

Comment: but i want them to display. i dont want them to display only in this module. so i think i have to edit the code part above

Comment: You still haven't advised what module you are using - Virtuemart is the component?

Comment: component: virtuemart,   module: sj ajax tabs for vm

Answer (score 1):

In your module, as you have $productModel you can check $productModel->orderable. Now where ever your products in module are rendered make a check like -

```
if ($productModel->orderable == false) {
    //Do not render product
} else {
    //Render product
}
```